# Match values from one list of dictionary to other list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists of dicts as below

```
devices = [
    {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, 
    {'a': 'e', 'f': 'g'}, 
    {'h': 'i', 'j': 'k'}
]
```

```
alldicts = [
    {'a': {'eth1': 'b', 'eth2': 'e'}},
    {'c': {'eth1': 'd', 'eth2': 'o', 'eth3': 'q'}},
    {'f': {'eth1': 'g'}},
    {'h': {'eth1': 'i'}}, 
    {'j': {'eth1': 'k'}}
]
```

I want to have output list of dict such that the new list will have all the items from devices but will replace the values with the values from alldicts. So the desired output should be as below

Desired Output:

```
final_list = [
    {'a': 'eth1', 'c': 'eth1'}, 
    {'a': 'eth2', 'f': 'eth1'}, 
    {'h': 'eth1', 'j': 'eth1'}
]
```

Below is the code I am trying but it doesnt give me the desired output

```
final_int = []
for each in devices:
    for i,j in each.items():
        for each_dict in alldicts:
            for k,l in each_dict.items():
                for a,b in l.items():       
                    if b == j and i == k:
                        final_int.append({i:a})
```

Comment: Your question would be much easier to read and understand with simpler and shorter data

Comment: Apologies, I have put it in a shorter format now.

Comment: It will be easier if you use meaningful variable names instead of meaningless letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary dictionary to make searching for correct values easier:

```py
tmp = {}
for d in alldicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        for kk, ii in v.items():
            tmp.setdefault(k, {})[ii] = kk

out = [{k: tmp.get(k, {}).get(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in devices]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
  {'a': 'eth1', 'c': 'eth1'}, 
  {'a': 'eth2', 'f': 'eth1'}, 
  {'h': 'eth1', 'j': 'eth1'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert `alldicts` into a single dictionary, and invert the nested dictionaries.

```
dev_dict = {k: {v1: k1 for k1, v1 in d.items()} for ad in alldicts for k, d in ad.items()}
```

Then you can look up the replacement values directly.

```
final_int = [
    {k: dev_dict[k][v] for k, v in dev.items()}
    for dev in devices
]
```